# SQL display results from two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which is used in an application to display information of recent events

| Event ID | Severity | Job ID | Date | Program | Computer | Event Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63860289 | Information | 51513829 | 03/15/2023 16:10:00 | JobManager | tsxxcck | 19:1592 | Auxiliary Copy attempt... |
| 63860288 | Information | 51513828 | 03/15/2023 16:09:59 | JobManager | tsxxcck | 30:296 | Auxiliary Copy attempt... |
| 63860287 | Information | 51513827 | 03/15/2023 16:09:58 | JobManager | tsxxcck | 19:1592 | Auxiliary Copy attempt... |
| 63860286 | Information | 51513826 | 03/15/2023 16:09:57 | JobManager | tsxxcck | 30:381 | Auxiliary Copy attempt... |
| 63860285 | Information | 51513825 | 03/15/2023 16:09:56 | JobManager | tsxxcck | 19:1592 | Auxiliary Copy attempt... |

```
SELECT  EvMsg.id, jobId_l, severity, timeSource, subsystem, client,
    CAST (L.SubsystemID AS VARCHAR(10))+':'+CAST (L.MessageNum AS VARCHAR(19)),
    ISNULL(EvMsgCache.Message, DBO.fn_EvFormatEventMsgText(EvMsg.id, @locId, EvMsg.MessageId, 1,2)),
    CL.displayName
FROM EvMsg
JOIN EvLocaleMsgs L ON EvMsg.messageId = L.MessageID AND L.LocaleID = @locId
WHERE timeSource >= @startTime
```

I want to display only events with event code 30:296 and 30:381, from the SELECT statement I see the Event Code is made from two fields (SubsystemID and MessageNum) which are Int values of a different table named EvLocaleMsgs

```
CAST (L.SubsystemID AS VARCHAR(10))+':'+CAST (L.MessageNum AS VARCHAR(19))
```

I tried to add the below condition but it doesn't filter the event codes

```
AND L.SubsystemID = 30 AND L.MessageNum IN (296, 381)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You filter as shown looks like it will filter certain rows, how they relate to your event code I have no idea. You need to provide a [mre] with sample data (ideally as DDL+DML), desired results and your attempt. Emphasis on *minimal* we don't need you entire complex query, just enough to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Also, instead of the image . I would generate a `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement so that others can quickly build a playground to better help you out ..

Comment: so the query is used by a report that comes with an application, what I understand in the SELECT statement the Error Code xx:xx is made from 2 fields of a different table called (EvLocaleMsgs). I want to specific only list the error code 30:296 and 30:381

CAST (L.SubsystemID AS VARCHAR(10))+':'+CAST (L.MessageNum AS VARCHAR(19)),

Comment: I don't understand. What is this "Error Code" you are talking about? I don't understand what the question is here.

Comment: The columns in your sample data do not match the query column output. That starts to make this confusing. I would start by looking at l.subsystemID and l.messagenum to see if those values truly are as you think they are. You're casting them , so maybe they look different in the database table.

Comment: But more likely, do you have a hanging "OR" somewhere in the where clause that is not enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: As shown your query will work... we need a [mre] that shows it not working. Making a DBFiddle which demonstrates this behaviour might be your best bet.

Comment: @Isolated, they are casted to concatenate both Int values. I verified the values of subsystemID and messagenum in EvLocaleMsgs table and they are Int, I'm not a SQL expert apologies for the bad explaining. The table I posted is the result of the query. The result I want is only to display the values 30:296 and 30:381 in the column Event Code

Comment: Your original query had an `OR` operator. Is there a chance you added your additional criteria within the contents of this operator? For example, `where color = 'red' or type = 'fruit' and price > 20` would not produce the results you may think. You would need to use parenthesis in the right place. Also, your sample query still doesn't match your sample table.

Comment: @Isolated this is the original where clause with the modification I added to filter the Event code, the OR operator is right in its place

`
    WHERE timeSource >= @startTime AND timeSource <= @endTime AND type <> 2
  AND L.SubsystemID = 30 AND L.MessageNum IN (296, 381)
     AND (@canUserViewAll = 1 OR dbo.isClientVisibleEvents(@userId, jobId_l, EvMsg.CommcellId, clientId, userID, libraryId, maClientId, mediaId, driveId) > 0)
`
the weird thing is that it doesn't throw an error it is just still displaying all the Even Codes